# How to concatenate the result of two linux commands?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tr

Is there an easy way to concatenate the result of two linux commands, in one line? (i.e without using variables)

I pull the local outdoor temperature from a nearby weather station. The result today is:
 `5.2`
I simply want to add the units, so result should look like this:
 `5.2°C`

An example command, that almost gives me what I want is:
`wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)' ; printf "°C\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already concatenating the results.

`wget .. | grep ..` outputs: `5.2\n`

`printf` outputs `°C\n`

The concatenated result is therefore `5.2\n°C\n` , exactly what you're getting.

What you want to do is strip the linefeed after `5.2`. You can take advantage of the fact that `$(command substitution)` strips trailing linefeeds and pass it to `printf`:

```
printf '%s°C\n' "$(wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)')"
```

Answer (score 1):

in bash, add pipe at the end:

```
echo $(cat) [more text]
```

or

```
echo `cat` [more text]
```

example:

```
wget -q -O- "http://meteocentre.com/montreal/home_e.html" | grep -oP '(?<=Tn= ).*(?=&deg)' | echo $(cat) °C
```

-> 5.2 °C